# Allow async/await for messaging function? C#

Tags: c#, async-await

I have some generic code used for our messaging system that allows us to send immutable messages and subscribes to the response.

The usual method signature for these commands is:

`public void OnCallMade(SomeCommand cmd, CancellationToken ct = default)`

However, I want to be able to have an `async` function, but I'm unsure how to write this. We subscribe to the command with the following function call:

```
    public static IConnection SubscribeToCmd<TCmd>(this IConnection connection, string name, Action<TCmd, CancellationToken> handler)
      where TCmd : TarCmd<TCmd>
    {
      return connection.Subscribe(TarCmd<TCmd>.GetS(name), handler);
    }
```

Any advice would be appreciated as I know the `Action` part will need to change but not entirely sure how to make it async.

Comment: Check out MVVM messenger from Microsoft's own community toolkit - specifically relay command and async relay command. These will give you some ideas on the implementation.

Comment: You need to extend the invocation part as well. Not only the subscription/registration of the handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You exact ask is not very clear. But use Func instead of Action. An Action is a delegate for methods which return void. However, every async method returns a Task or Task where T is a return value.

So your caller would have a delegate like

```
Func<Task,TCmd> SomeEvent {get; set;}
```

and it will be invoked as

```
async Task SendMessage(TCmd msg) 
{
 if(SomeEvent!=null) 
 {
  await SomeEvent(msg);
 }
}
```